# How can I see the exact Docker image that I'm using?

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I have a fresh install of Docker on Windows 11. I've updated WSL2.
In PowerShell I've run the command to install Memgraph Platform:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\mjones> wsl --update
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.
PS C:\Users\mjones> docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform
Unable to find image 'memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from memgraph/memgraph-platform
bbeef03cda1f: Pull complete
02daf11f09c6: Pull complete
5af8c9d8a2b2: Pull complete
0491e760b2fc: Pull complete
eb6fb9e064cc: Pull complete
d5d9807e2348: Pull complete
380fd2f22c95: Pull complete
1dfa183f30c6: Pull complete
f82d62f564a4: Pull complete
73b2e2343891: Pull complete
0a07ae5e7150: Pull complete
0ade360c640a: Pull complete
a5d9a38455ce: Pull complete
b334dbe05140: Pull complete
8d4b2a9136fb: Pull complete
f89e8fe0da1d: Pull complete
ab8f88c89515: Pull complete
1673e45f8514: Pull complete
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d0c983be57497f098be23324b604cbdf5ad6fc29dbb90bdad909ada1da9f73ab
Status: Downloaded newer image for memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest
Memgraph Lab is running at localhost:3000

mgconsole 1.3
Connected to 'memgraph://127.0.0.1:7687'
Type :help for shell usage
Quit the shell by typing Ctrl-D(eof) or :quit
memgraph>
```

Is there a docker command that I can use to check which exactly version of Memgraph Platform was installed? I can see that the tag is `latest`, but how can I tell to which image does it correspond?

I've taken a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/memgraph/memgraph-platform/tags and I still don't get it. I'm new to Docker. Is there a command that would says "lastes is in fact 2.6.5-memgraph2.5.2-lab2.4.0-mage1.6"? I pruse this on the fact that those two images have the same `DIGEST`

Comment: mostly latest tag refers to latest version of image. In that case your image may be refer to latest version "2.6.5-memgraph2.5.2-lab2.4.0-mage1.6".

Comment: Is there a way to see it without visiting Docker Hub web site? Some commands that I could put into PowerShell or a property that I can check in Docker Desktop?

Comment: as per my knowledge it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't get that info. The closes that you can get to obtaining that info is `docker image inspect` command.

Here is the first part of the output:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:3e1361a1a8b9a44ca89a6491cfe6fcc7501f4a0923e69a682edafffd8d0e9461",
        "RepoTags": [
            "memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "memgraph/memgraph-platform@sha256:d0c983be57497f098be23324b604cbdf5ad6fc29dbb90bdad909ada1da9f73ab"
```

As it can be seen tag is `memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest` so the version number can't be obtained.